# Jquery validation error message in checkbox validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having a issue with jquery validation styling. I'm using jquery validation additional-methods to validate one of two fields must filled and one of them is a checkbox. issue is error only gets the checkbox width. as in the image bellow.[image]

how can i solve this. thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your code?  Please just don't dump a picture with no code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to work around it. My checkbox name is 'single_service'. firstly i hide the label error message that created by validation plugin with simple css.

```
label#single_service-error {display: none !important; }
```

then i added invalidHandler ([Documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#options)) function that validation plugin provided to show my error in side an element that i created instead of it's label.

```
invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                console.log(validator.submitted);
                if (validator.submitted.single_service!=''){
                    $(".single_service_error").html(validator.submitted.single_service);
                    console.log('error');
                } else {
                    $(".single_service_error").html(' ');
                    console.log('no-error');
                }
            }
```

Full function like this.

```
$("#add_form").validate({
            rules: {
            },
            invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                if (validator.invalid.single_service!=undefined){
                    $(".single_service_error").html(validator.submitted.single_service);
                } else {
                    $(".single_service_error").html('');
                }
            }
        });
```

i hope someone will find this useful.

Comment: Using `errorPlacement` is the better and more practical way to handle "placing errors".  You would use a conditional function within.  *"If checkbox, place error message here, else place error message in default location"*